# Monodroid WebView Loading SSL page

Tags: c#, ssl, webview, xamarin.android

I have tried loading a WebView with a SSL page, and I am getting an error. Code and error below. I have set my permissions to allow Internet access.

I think this is a Mono-only issue. When I try my SSL web page in the default browser it works fine.

```
WebView webView = new WebView(this);
string website = "https://...";
webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
webView.SetWebViewClient(new WebViewClientAuthentication());
webView.LoadUrl(website);

//definition for WebViewClientAuthentication
public class WebViewClientAuthentication : WebViewClient
{
    public override void OnReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, Android.Net.Http.SslError error)
    {
        Log.Error("SSL ERROR",string.Format("SSL ERROR: {0}, Primary: {1}", error.GetType.ToString(), error.PrimaryError.ToString()));
        base.OnReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**
SSL ERROR: Android.Net.Http.SslError, Primary: Notyetvalid

**COMMENTS**
I have seen this message: http://mono-for-android.1047100.n5.nabble.com/SSL-issues-td5629485.html - but I am not sure what it means in terms of loading SSL sites into a webview.

Comment: Pretty crappy UI stackoverflow - I get subtracted reputation if the answerer of my question removes his account... The least you could do is leave the answer there and associate the answer with an "unknown account" - Now I can't remember the answer to even put it up myself!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
//definition for WebViewClientAuthentication
public class WebViewClientAuthentication : WebViewClient
{
    public override void OnReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, Android.Net.Http.SslError error)
    {
        handler.Proceed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey I'll take it! It's nearly a year since I had this problem and it was solved, but the user left SO.com and I lost the answer.... Check out my comment on the question :)

Comment: Does the trick but this should never be used in production. This ignores SSL errors which is never a great idea.

Comment: Google automatically rejects updates which use this code https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/7071387