# Xamarian Webview only https sites working not http sites

Tags: xamarin.android

How to make http  web sites work in xamarian webview. 
its working only  when i use https sites

eg: 
    http://www.google.com  // Not working

```
https://www.google.com  // working
```

Answer (score 0):

//definition for WebViewClientAuthentication

```
public class WebViewClientAuthentication : WebViewClient
{
    public override void OnReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, Android.Net.Http.SslError error)
    {
        handler.Proceed();
    }
}
```

**this will ignore the ssl error & it works**

Found answer from the below link

[Monodroid WebView Loading SSL page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12034452/monodroid-webview-loading-ssl-page)

Answer (score 0):

`WebView` support URLs formed with the protocol specified (i.e. it must have "http://" or "https://" prepended to it).

Based on my test, `http://www.google.com` works well. Please check your network.

```
var browser = new WebView();
        browser.Source = "http://www.google.com";//"https://www.google.com";//"http://xamarin.com";
        Content = browser;
```

[image]